# Where can I see fb_ref data?

Tags: statistics, facebook-like, ref

I have an external page with like button which likes my Facebook page.

The like button is an app with app_id and so on.

The button is called via

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/My.Page?ref=likegametest20120723&fb_ref=likegametest20120723&fb_source=likegametest20120723" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" ref="likegameref" fb_ref="likegamefbref" fb_source="likegamefbsource"></div>
```

The button works like it should but I can't find any of these ref's in insights or elsewhere.

Where should I look for it?

Answer (score 1):

`fb_ref` values aren't tracked by Facebook. Facebook simply passes the `fb_ref` values to your app / website letting you track them yourself (i.e. using Google Analytics).

Quote from Facebook:

> Specifying a value for the ref attribute adds the 'fb_ref' parameter
>   to the any links back to your site which are clicked from within the
>   plugin. Using different values for the ref parameter for different
>   positions and configurations of this plugin within your pages allows
>   you to track which instances are performing the best.

Comment: so there's no way to distinguish likers of the Facebook Page from within the Facebook for example to count their shares in total number of fans or track their activity level searately?

Comment: In a way. If you generate a `fb_ref` for a user randomly and then listen for the `event.subscribe` when Liking something, you can tie the two together to track Likes. Haven't tried it myself so can't validate how the entire process would work.